# Exp:resso store price based on login

Tags: expresso-store

I have a question about Exp:resso store. I need to develop a webshop where different prices are handeld per group member.

Each group has different pricelevels. For example a product has the following prices:

- Group consumer: 15,-
- Group business: 12,50
- Group retailers: 10,-

So I want to set fixed prices, not a discount percentage! Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This currently does not exist in Store at the product level. There is a considerable sales/discounts system that allows you to tie it to groups and items, but it is reverse from the way you are thinking.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it outside the scope of expresso-store.

You would have to create three separate products which are identical in every way but price and then use Expressionengine's built in conditionals to display them based upon user group.